# How can I build an $or query for MongoDB using the Java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java-driver

I'm trying to Or some conditions in MongoDB (using the Java driver). This is what I'm doing :

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("title");   
DBCollection coll = MongoDBUtil.getDB().getCollection("post_details");

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("category_title", "myCategory");      
query.append("post_title", regex);  
query.append("post_description", regex);    

DBCursor cur = coll.find(query);
while(cur.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cur.next().get("post_id"));
}
```

I'd like to use the `$or` operand on these conditions, but I guess the default is "and" and I don't know how to change it. In the above code if one of the conditions returns `null`, the result will be `null` too.

Comment: 'code' query.append("$or", new BasicDBObject().append("post_title", regex).append("post_description", regex))

Comment: That doesn't look right. $or clauses are wrapped by an array not an object.

Comment: guys please answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115986/writing-mongodb-syntax
please i need your help >_<

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You are correct that the "default" for specifying multiple field in a query is that each field serves as a conditional filter, and thus is an AND operation.

You can perform MongoDB queries with an OR clause by using the $or operand which has the following syntax :

```
db.col.find({$or:[clause1, clause2]})
```

Where each clause can be a query. $or does not have to be a top level operand but if it is MongoDB can use an index for each seperate clause.

In your example you want to end up with this query :

```
db.col.find({$or:[{"post_title", regex}, {"post_description", regex}]});
```

Which can be constructed in Java through :

```
DBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("post_title", regex);  
DBObject clause2 = new BasicDBObject("post_description", regex);    
BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
or.add(clause1);
or.add(clause2);
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", or);
```

Comment: thnx , let me test it and get back 2 u . :)

Comment: I tried this approach in MongoDB 3.2 with Java driver 3.2.2 and I get the error: `Can't resolve the method dbColl.find(DBObject)`. Can you, please, update the answer for the actual Java driver version.

Comment: Please, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753254/how-to-execute-queries-with-both-and-and-or-clauses-in-mongodb-with-java

Answer (score 13):

With [filters](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html) you could build yours like:

```
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;
...

Bson filter = Filters.or(
                    Filters.eq("post_title", regex), 
                    Filters.eq("post_description", regex)
                  );
```