# MongoDB and JAVA - Logical OR with Regex query

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to create an equivalant of the following SQL query:

```
Select * from X where a like 'a%' OR b like 'a%'
```

I tried all sorts of options but I keep getting the following error:

```
falsecom.mongodb.MongoException: $or requires nonempty array
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly did you try out in Mongo when you got that exception?

Comment: What library are you using? What's the code of your query?

Comment: You may take inspiration from this


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620771/how-to-or-few-conditions-in-mongodb-using-java-driver/10620972#10620972

Comment: Thanks a lot Ravi, it works using this approach!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the QueryBuilder class to make the code a bit more readable:

```
    Mongo m = new Mongo();
    m.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);
    DBCollection c = m.getDB("test").getCollection("or-test");
    c.drop();

    c.insert(new BasicDBObject("a", "abba"));
    c.insert(new BasicDBObject("b", "abba"));
    c.insert(new BasicDBObject("a", "bbba"));
    c.insert(new BasicDBObject("b", "bbba"));

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^a");
    DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start().or(
            QueryBuilder.start("a").regex(pattern).get(),
            QueryBuilder.start("b").regex(pattern).get()
            ).get();
    System.out.println(c.find(query).count());
```

This will print "2".