# how to search in mongodb java with multiple conditions in where clause

Tags: java, mongodb

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53ace08c98dea42bb1cb84ba"),
  "id" : "xyz",
}
```

select this collection where `id = "xyz"` or `id = "abc"`

how to write this query in mongodb by Java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I build an $or query for MongoDB using the Java driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620771/how-can-i-build-an-or-query-for-mongodb-using-the-java-driver)

Answer (score 4):

You can use OR clause by using the $or operand to perform mongodb queries.

db.col.find({$or:[clause1, clause2]})

```
DBObject document1 = new BasicDBObject("id", "abc");  
DBObject document2 = new BasicDBObject("id", "xyz");       

or.add(document1);
or.add(document2);

DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", or);

DBCursor cur=db.getCollection("user").find(query);//user is the collection

while(cur.hasNext()){
System.out.println(cur.next());
}
```

You can go through this link too [How can I build an $or query for MongoDB using the Java driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620771/how-to-or-few-conditions-in-mongodb-using-java-driver)