# How to execute queries with both AND and OR clauses in MongoDB with Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java-driver

I want to execute query in MongoDB 3.2 with Java Driver 3.2, which contains both `$and` and `$or` clauses at the same time.

With the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10621210/462347), I tried the following approach:

```java
List<Document> criteria1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Document> criteria2 = new ArrayList<>();

criteria1.add(new Document("fetchStatus", new Document("$gte", FetchStatus.PROCESSED_NLP.getID())));
criteria1.add(new Document("fetchStatus", new Document("$lte", fetchStatusParam)));
criteria1.add(new Document("episodeID", new Document("$in", episodeIDs)));

criteria2.add(new Document("fetchStatus", new Document("$eq", PROCESSED_FETCH.getID())));
criteria2.add(new Document("isFullTextRet", new Document("$eq", false)));

BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
or.add(criteria1);
or.add(criteria2);

DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", or);
ArrayList<Document> results = dbC_Coll.find(query).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Where the `criteria1` and `criteria2` should be connected with `$or` while within `criteria1` clause the `$and` should be applied.

The problem is that in MongoDB Java Driver 3.2 there is such no method and I get the `Cannot resolve method find(com.mongodb.DBObject)` error.

How can I compose a query such as `(A && B) || (X && Y)` in MongoDB Java Driver 3.2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I find it far less confusing to construct the object sequences just like U would with a JSON structure to enhance readability. But it's still just `Document()` wherever you see `{}` and `List` wherever you see `[]`:

```
Document query = new Document(
    "$or", Arrays.asList(
        // First document in $or
        new Document(
            "fetchStatus", 
            new Document( "$gte", FetchStatus.PROCESSED_NLP.getID() )
            .append("$lte", fetchStatusParam)
        )
        .append("episodeID", new Document( "$in", episodeIDs)),
        // Second document in $or
        new Document("fetchStatus", PROCESSED_FETCH.getID())
        .append("isFullTextRet", false)
    )
);
```

Which is basically the same as:

```
   {
       "$or": [
           {
               "fetchStatus": { 
                   "$gte": FetchStatus.PROCESS_NLP.getID(),
                   "$lte": fetchStatusParam
               },
               "episodeID": { "$in": episodeIDs }
           },
           {
               "fetchStatus": PROCESSED_FETCH.getID(),
               "isFullTextRet": false
           }
       ]
   }
```

Also there is no need for "explicit" `$eq` operators, since "equals" is actually the default meaning of a value assignment in a query property anyway.