# How can I compose a query such as (A || B || C) && (X || Y) in MongoDB Java Driver 3.2

Tags: java, mongodb

Unfortunately, I cannot find an example for Mongo 3.2 java driver for query like "(A or B or C) and (D or E or F or G)"

Number of parameters inside parentheses will be variable - **up to hundred**.

Funny thing that I've found example for "(A && B) || (X && Y)" but it doesn't help me.

[How to execute queries with both AND and OR clauses in MongoDB with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753254/how-to-execute-queries-with-both-and-and-or-clauses-in-mongodb-with-java)

My code produces error:

**MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message '$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects'**

```
List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<>();

for (Integer ln: input.getLastnames()) {
        docs.add(new Document("lastname",ln));
    }

    Document queryLN = new Document(
            "$or", Arrays.asList(docs)
    );

    docs.clear();
    for (Integer fn: input.getFirstnames()) {
        docs.add(new Document("firstname",fn));
    }

    Document queryFN = new Document(
            "$or", Arrays.asList(docs)
    );

    Document query = new Document(
            "$and", Arrays.asList(queryFN,queryLN));

    List<Document> result = collectionMain.find(query).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

Comment: In your case `Arrays.asList(List<Document>)` produces `List<List<ListDocument>>`. In the example you referenced it's `List<Document>`. I'd blame that.

Comment: Changing Arrays.asList(docs) to docs removed the error, but results were not near (A or B) and (C or D). Sort of A or B or C or D. @saurav s suggestion is complete. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an "in" query in such condition when you have a long unknown list of OR conditions.

An example code:

```
try {
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
        DB db = mongo.getDB("so");
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("employees");

        List<Integer> ageList = new ArrayList<>();
        ageList.add(30);
        ageList.add(35);

        List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
        nameList.add("Anna");

        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$and", Arrays.asList(
            new BasicDBObject("age", new BasicDBObject("$in", ageList)),
            new BasicDBObject("name", new BasicDBObject("$in", nameList)))
        );

        DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
        while(cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
}catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

To experiment with the above code, you can add the following entries in your MongoDB:

```
db.employees.insert({"name":"Adma","dept":"Admin","languages":["german","french","english","hindi"],"age":30, "totalExp":10});
db.employees.insert({"name":"Anna","dept":"Admin","languages":["english","hindi"],"age":35, "totalExp":11});
db.employees.insert({"name":"Bob","dept":"Facilities","languages":["english","hindi"],"age":36, "totalExp":14});
db.employees.insert({"name":"Cathy","dept":"Facilities","languages":["hindi"],"age":31, "totalExp":4});
db.employees.insert({"name":"Mike","dept":"HR","languages":["english", "hindi", "spanish"],"age":26, "totalExp":3});
db.employees.insert({"name":"Jenny","dept":"HR","languages":["english", "hindi", "spanish"],"age":25, "totalExp":3});
```

The above code produces this query:

```
db.employees.find({"$and":[{"age":{"$in":[30, 35]}},{"name":{"$in":["Anna"]}}]});
```

And the output is:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "57ff3e5e3dedf0228d4862ad"} , "name" : "Anna" , "dept" : "Admin" , "languages" : [ "english" , "hindi"] , "age" : 35.0 , "totalExp" : 11.0}
```

A good article on this topic: https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-query-document/

Read these as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8219679/3896066 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/14738878/3896066

Comment: Huge thanks, saurav! So sorry, that bounty cannot be splitted. 4J41-s answer arrived a bit later, but is much more personal. Couldn't ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first understand your code. We will make it simple by replacing the for loops with simple statements and add some print statements.

```
List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<>();

docs.add(new Document("lastname","Walker"));
docs.add(new Document("lastname","Harris"));    

Document queryLN = new Document("$or", Arrays.asList(docs));

docs.clear();

System.out.println(queryLN.toJson());//{ "$or" : [[]] } 

docs.add(new Document("firstname", "Pat"));
docs.add(new Document("firstname", "Matt"));

Document queryFN = new Document("$or", Arrays.asList(docs));

System.out.println(queryLN.toJson());//{ "$or" : [[{ "firstname" : "Pat" }, { "firstname" : "Matt" }]] }
System.out.println(queryFN.toJson());//{ "$or" : [[{ "firstname" : "Pat" }, { "firstname" : "Matt" }]] }

Document query = new Document("$and", Arrays.asList(queryFN, queryLN));

System.out.println(query.toJson());//{ "$and" : [{ "$or" : [[{ "firstname" : "Pat" }, { "firstname" : "Matt" }]] }, { "$or" : [[{ "firstname" : "Pat" }, { "firstname" : "Matt" }]] }] }

List<Document> result = collectionMain.find(query).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

**Observations:**

- `docs` is already a list. Using `Arrays.asList` on `docs`, creates a list of list, which is not acceptable for the `$and, $or, $nor`. These operators accept a `list of Documents`. That explains the error message.
- `Arrays.asList` does not create a copy of the array or the list that it receives. It just creates a wrapper over it. Also, `new document()` does not copy the list that it receives with "$or", just references the original list. Hence, calling `docs.clear()` will reset the content in `$or` of `queryLN`.
- Also, the above concept explains why the 2nd and 3rd print statements give the same output.

Let us get the code working now.

```
List<Document> docsLN = new ArrayList<Document>();
List<Document> docsFN = new ArrayList<Document>();

for (Integer ln: input.getLastnames()) {
    docsLN.add(new Document("lastname",ln));
}           

Document queryLN = new Document("$or", docsLN);

for (Integer fn: input.getFirstnames()) {
    docsFN.add(new Document("firstname",fn));
}

Document queryFN = new Document("$or", docsFN);

System.out.println(queryLN.toJson());
System.out.println(queryFN.toJson());

Document query = new Document("$and", Arrays.asList(queryFN, queryLN));

System.out.println(query.toJson());
List<Document> result = collectionMain.find(query).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

Also, consider replacing the `$or` with `$in`.

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-versus-in):

> When using $or with  that are equality checks for the
>   value of the same field, use the $in operator instead of the $or
>   operator.

Comment: Huge thanks for reviewing my shameful code and pointing at other bugs!