# MongoDB: Query with an or statement

Tags: java, mongodb

MongoDB version 3.0.6

So I have this query where I want to perform some less than and greater than operations. Additionally, I want perform an `or` operation, but I can't figure out the syntax for that in java. Below is what I have so far:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable3 = db.getCollection(collectionName).find(
    new Document()
        .append("timestamp", new Document()
               .append("$gte", startTime)
               .append("$lte", endTime))
        .append("hourOfDay", new Document()
                .append("$gte", minHourOfDay)
                .append("$lte", maxHourOfDay))
        .append("dayOfWeek", new Document()
                .append("$or", new Document("2","4")))
```

);

What I want is the query to also check if the `dayOfWeek` parameter is either equal to `2` or `4`.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620771/how-can-i-build-an-or-query-for-mongodb-using-the-java-driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator as follows:

```
db.collection.find({ 
    "timestamp": { "$gte": startTime, "$lte": endTime },
    "hourOfDay": { "$gte": minHourOfDay, "$lte": maxHourOfDay },
    "dayOfWeek": { "$in": [2, 4] }
});
```

The above query is a much simpler version of the following query with the [**`$or`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator:

```
db.collection.find({ 
    "timestamp": { "$gte": startTime, "$lte": endTime },
    "hourOfDay": { "$gte": minHourOfDay, "$lte": maxHourOfDay },
    "$or": [
        { "dayOfWeek": 2 },
        { "dayOfWeek": 4 }
    ]
});
```

So your final Java code would look like

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable3 = db.getCollection(collectionName).find(
    new Document()
        .append("timestamp", new Document()
               .append("$gte", startTime)
               .append("$lte", endTime))
        .append("hourOfDay", new Document()
                .append("$gte", minHourOfDay)
                .append("$lte", maxHourOfDay))
        .append("dayOfWeek", new Document("$in", Arrays.asList(2, 4)));
);
```