# writing mongoDB syntax

Tags: java, mongodb, syntax

hey guys how to write this mongoDB syntax to java

```
db.users.find( { user_id: /bc/ },{user_name:/bc/},{age:/2/} )
```

my source is

```
BasicDBObject sortOrder = new BasicDBObject();
MongoClient mongoClient;
DB db;

DBCollection table;
DBCursor cursor = null;

mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
db = mongoClient.getDB("stackoverflow");
boolean auth = db.authenticate("aku","kamu".toCharArray());
table = db.getCollection("questions");
cursor = table.find();

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    DBObject object = cursor.next();
    out.print(object.get("title"));
    answer = rn.nextInt(8) + 0;
}
```

any solution guys?
i am newbie on using mongoDB

Comment: sorry before, i mean how to add or clause on regex
i already add 

cursor = table.find(new BasicDBObject("title", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("milk")));

its succes, but how if i wanna add more regex like the question..thanks before :)

Comment: share what you have tried already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    DBObject idMatch = new BasicDBObject("user_id","bc");
    DBObject usernameMatch = new BasicDBObject("user_name",bc);
    DBObject ageMatch = new BasicDBObject("age",2);

    DBObject andAll = new BasicDBObject("$and", Arrays.asList(existence, firstNotMatch, secondNotMatch));

    //calling  table.find will get you what you wanted.
    table.find(andAll);
```

If you want to 'OR' the conditions, just replace $and with $or.
note that the above code is not tested properly and you may need to modify it a bit to make it work.

Your question is not clear, but i hope i helped.

Comment: how to print the resutl mate?